# Save CQ Component field value as Long instead of String

Tags: aem

I am trying to save the value entered by an Author in a [NumberField](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/current/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.Ext.form.NumberField) as a 'Long' instead of 'String'. Is there a way to configure this or do I have write something custom?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [TypeHints](http://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/manipulating-content-the-slingpostservlet-servlets-post.html#typehint). Add a hidden field (xtype:hidden) with name = <numberField'sName>@TypeHint and value= Long

Comment: Thanks Sharath! This is what my dialog.xml looks like. And it is not working. Any ideas why?


<noOfViews
                    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                    fieldLabel="No. of Views"
                    name="./noOfViews"
                    xtype="numberfield"/>
<noOfViewsHint
                    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                    ignoreData="{Boolean}true"
                    name="./noOfViews@TypeHint"
                    value="Decimal"
                    xtype="hidden"/>

Comment: Decimal is not a valid value for the TypeHint.  Change it to Long.  E.g. name="./noOfViews@TypeHint" value="Long"

Comment: @mayurM try without the ignoreData attribute

Comment: @SharathMadappa that din't work either. Here is the updated XML
<noOfViews
                    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                    fieldLabel="No. of Views"
                    name="./noOfViews"
                    xtype="numberfield"/>
                <noOfViewsHint 
                 jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget" 
                 name="./noOfViews@TypeHint" 
                 value="Long" 
                 xtype="hidden"/>

Answer (score 1):

Add as below for double value and its failing for decimal value i.e. its not allowing decimal values

```
<price jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/numberfield"
fieldLabel="Product Price"
name="./price"/>
<priceHint jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/hidden"
name="./price@TypeHint" 
value="Double"
defaultValue="Double"/>
```

Comment: @VeraAung it does not work for me for Double and Decimal values, when we try to enter a value like 45.33 gives validation message.

Comment: I'm not sure about Double as typeHint for number field, but referencing this code and using Long (not Double) worked for me. https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/ref/granite-ui/api/jcr_root/libs/granite/ui/components/foundation/form/numberfield/index.html

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me. :)

```
<noOfViews jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget" fieldLabel="No. of Views" name="./noOfViews" xtype="numberfield"/>
<noOfViewsHint jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget" defaultValue="Long" name="./noOfViews@TypeHint" value="Long" xtype="hidden"/>
```